# Cannot delete line and the combobox upon it

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have a worksheet creating ActiveX Comboboxes when the user adds a text in a specific column.
Specifically, the user enters a string in a cell of column A and a macro then get the text and creates a combobox over the very same cell.

Now, I would like to add a Delete button besides the newly created combobox in order to delete the same row.

I managed to create the combobox and the button too but 'sometimes' I have an error in the row deletion: in particular the row is correctly deleted but the combobox still persists. I don't understand the issue since it does not occur every time.

How I add the comboboxes and the delete button (in a Worksheet_change handler):

```
    Dim cb As OLEObject

    Set cb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=targ.Left, Top:=targ.Top, Width:=targ.Width, Height:=targ.Height)
    cb.LinkedCell = targ.Address

    For Each cell In paramRange
        cb.Object.AddItem cell.value
    Next cell

    Dim delBtn As Button
    Set delBtn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(ActiveSheet.Cells(targ.row, 13).Left, ActiveSheet.Cells(targ.row, 13).Top, ActiveSheet.Cells(targ.row, 13).Width, ActiveSheet.Cells(targ.row, 13).Height)

    With delBtn
        .OnAction = "DeleteLine"
        .Caption = "DELETE"
        .name = targ.row
    End With
```

The macro related to the pression of the delete button:

```
For Each OleObj in ActiveSheet.Rows(CInt(Application.Caller.row)).OLEObjects 
   oleObj.Delete
Next oleObj.Delete

Rows(CInt(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).name)).Delete
```

As I said, most of the times the related row AND the associated combobox is deleted nicely, but sometimes only the row is deleted while the combobox still hangs in its place.

Comment: Have you attempted to name the button in a way that captures the row it is tied to?  E.g., button "cat_|1" is on row 1 and "cat_|30" is on row 30, so you can use `instr(cell,"_|")` to find the location of the row number and use that to loop through your activex controls and delete the one with the name of the row being deleted.

Comment: Try to qualify your sheet. Using `ActiveSheet` can cause issues like this. Saying that, where does the code to delete reside?

Comment: Tried both the approaches with no noticeable success.